# How to I get my text to display my score in Unity?

Tags: javascript, string, text, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am programming a game, and I want the text to show the player score, which increases over time. However, it is not working. Why wont it work?

```
#pragma strict
import UnityEngine.UI;
var score = 0;
var highScore : int;
var text : Text;
function Start() {
    highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score");
    text = GetComponent(Text);
    text.text = score.ToString();
}
function Update() {
    score += Time.deltaTime;
    if (score >= highScore) {
        highScore = score;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", highScore);
    }
    text.text = score.ToString();
}
```

I keep getting the error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Timer and Scoreboard.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Timer and Scoreboard.js:17)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you have already assigned `Text` component called Score to the `text` slot in the Editor but then you override that when you did `text = GetComponent(Text);` in your Start function. Simply remove `text = GetComponent(Text);` and your code should work.

If you want to know why `text = GetComponent(Text);` is returning null, that's because there is no `Text` component attached to the-same GameObject(Main Camera) the script is attached to. `text = GameObject.Find("In-Game UI/Score").GetComponent(Text);` should work fine. You don't have to do this since you have already assigned the `Text` from the Editor.

Comment: I got rid of the GetComponent(Text);, and it didn't change anything

Comment: Oops, it was something else. Thank you!